# Using Offset (Runtime error 424 object required)

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error, offset

I want the program to look for “1” in column “U34:U99”  .And on the order number of  “1” checked the value in certain sheets .
For example : First  “1”  (Лист1),Second “1”   (Лист2) …
But the error jumps out (Runtime error 424 object required) in line : 
If С.Offset(0, -5).Value = 1 And C.Value = 1 Then

```
    Sub обща()
    'для ситуации

    Dim k As Long, n As Long
    Dim C As Range
    Dim Diapozon As Range
    Set Diapozon = Range("U34:U99")
    k = 0
    n = 0
    For Each C In Diapozon.Rows

    If С.Offset(0, -5).Value = 1 And C.Value = 1 Then
    k = k + 1
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Лист" & k & "").Range("R100").Value = 1 Then
    n = n + 1
    End If
    End If

    Next C
    MsgBox n

    End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of `For Each C In Diapozon.Rows` try `For Each C In Diapozon`

Comment: @UGP , same result

Comment: Strange, even if i use `.Rows` what is not working, i dont get the error and without `.Rows` it just works fine. And you are sure that the error is still in the same line?

Comment: @UGP, yes , in the same line . And when i remove the condition (С.Offset(0, -5).Value = 1) all works fine

Comment: Try `Cells(C.Row, 16).Value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that works:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()

    Dim k           As Long
    Dim n           As Long
    Dim C           As Range
    Dim Diapozon    As Range

    Set Diapozon = Range("A1:A10")

    k = 0
    n = 0

    For Each C In Diapozon.Rows

        If C.Offset(0, 5).Value = 1 And C.Value = 1 Then
            k = k + 1
            If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test" & k).Range("B10").Value = 1 Then
                n = n + 1
            End If
        End If

    Next C
    Debug.Print n

End Sub
```

I have changed the Ranges, the Worksheet name and the `MsgBox` to a debug.print. Possible errors are that you do not have a `ListN` or something else...